# How to construct a `select ... in` SQL query in nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I'm using nim and `db_sqlite` to fetch some rows with certain `_id`s from a database table. For example:

```
for row in db.fastRows("SELECT * FROM t WHERE _id IN (?, ?)", @["1", "2"]):
  echo row
```

This works as expected, however, the sequence at the end is constructed dynamically at runtime, which means I need a variable amount of `?` in the query. I end up creating a sequence with question marks, joining them, interpolating the string and turning it into a database query:

```
var qs : seq[string]
for id in ids:
  qs.add("?")
let query_string = """SELECT * FROM t WHERE _id IN ($1)""" % join(qs, ",")
let query = SqlQuery(query_string)
for row in db.fastRows(query, ids):
  echo row
```

Is there a better way to construct a `select ... in` query in nim? Ideally one with just one `?` in the `SqlQuery`.

(For what it's worth, the current behavior is similar to other languages I've used)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do the replacement manually, here's one way using strformat and map

```
import strformat,db_sqlite,sequtils,strutils
#assuming ids is a seq[string] here
let query = sql(&"SELECT * FROM t WHERE _id IN ({ids.map(dbQuote).join(\",\")})")
for row in db.fastRows(query):
  echo row
```